# Shortcut to reveal in Finder for currently opened file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard short cut to open currently open file in the finder? I know it can be done like below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not present but we can add it. Go to `Preferences` -> `Keymap` and then search `Finder` (For Mac). There you see `Reveal in Finder`. DO right click and click `Add Keyboard Shortcut` there you can add your desired shortcut. See the image ->

1. Step 1

[image]

2. Step 2

[image]